# Two function in a event on React-Native

Tags: react-native, reactjs

How to put two function in a event like onValueChange?

I tried with

```
  onValueChange={(selected) => this.setState({selected}),this.state.eventOnChange}>
```

Comment: Why dont you create a function where you encapsulate calling these two functions?

Comment: Is a good choice, Thanks!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
onValueChange={(selected) => { 
    this.setState({selected});
    this.state.eventOnChange();
}}
```

Comment: That executes the first function , but not the second

Comment: @CarlosQuiroga just call it also like `this.state.eventOnChange();` , note the `()` in the end

Comment: That executes the first function , but not the second

Answer (score 2):

**Component.setState() is asynchronous and may be locked on the second call while it is still doing the first.**

**Do the second call in a callback like this:**

```
onValueChange=
    { (selected) => {
        this.setState(
            {category:selected},() => {this.filter();} // Add Functions That's you want to call.
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with the following code:

```
<TextInput
      style={{height: 40, width: 200, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, }}

      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({
        text
      }, () => {
        this._onChangeText();
      })
      } 
      autoCorrect={false}
      underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
      value={this.state.text}
    />
```

Thanks to @pinewood.

Answer (score 0):

```
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>  this.setState({id: itemValue}),this.getOtherFunction }
```