# How to call Two functions in a event on React-Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

**I would try : Source ( [Two function in a event on React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161344) )**

`onValueChange={(selected) => { 
    this.setState({selected});
    this.state.eventOnChange();
}}`

**But that's Not work**

**That executes the first function , but not the second.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Component.setState()` is asynchronous and may be locked on the second call while it is still doing the first.

Do the second call in a callback like this:

```
this.setState({selected},() => {
    this.state.eventOnChange();
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) @Cobolt That's Work

Answer (score 1):

Try to log a console after all functions

```
onValueChange={(selected) => { 
    this.setState({selected});
    this.state.eventOnChange();
    console.log('it works!');
}}
```

if its printing then there should be something wrong with second function call.