# React-native: Picker onValueChange setState lagging, do I need a setTimeout?

Tags: react-native, picker, setstate

In my React-native project I have a picker that, behind the scenes, chooses an array to use in a function.

```
 <Picker
      style={styles.onePicker} itemStyle={styles.onePickerItem}
      selectedValue={this.state.food}
      onValueChange={(itemValue) => { this.setState({food: itemValue}); this.cuisine();}}
    >
      <Picker.Item label="Italian" value="Italian" />
      <Picker.Item label="Chinese" value="Chinese" />
      <Picker.Item label="Cajun" value="Cajun" />
      <Picker.Item label="KFC" value="KFC" />
    </Picker>
```

It all works, but the setState does not get assigned before the function is run. In use, the array used is one picker section/action behind what's shown.

Is it normal to need a setTimeout, or whatever is used in react, for Pickers?

I also tried passing the itemValue in the cuisine function 
     this.cuisine(itemValue);

which calls:

cuisine = (data) => { the function stuff }

but in the console or in an alert to show the data passed I only get

```
 [object Object]
```

and not the actual value.

I'm a bit green in the use of ES6 and React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this it is working perfectly for me

```
 <View>
        <Picker        
          selectedValue={this.state.food}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) => {  this.cuisine(itemValue);}}>
          <Picker.Item label="Italian" value="Italian" />
          <Picker.Item label="Chinese" value="Chinese" />
          <Picker.Item label="Cajun" value="Cajun" />
          <Picker.Item label="KFC" value="KFC" />
  </Picker>

      <Text>{this.state.food}</Text>

  </View>
```

and now in the cuisine function

```
cuisine = (itemValue: any) => { 
   this.setState({food: itemValue});   
   console.log(this.state.food);
}
```

Comment: That looks nice and simple. But I am getting an error that tells me to "Objects are not valid as a React child ......... use and array instead". In Visual Code the error is: 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.ts(8010),

Comment: Sorted it out. Your solution worked but did not solve my problem, which was strange. So, after more digging, I needed to change the onValueChange to make sure it called another function with a callback which was needed to update the page. Like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920241/how-to-call-two-functions-in-a-event-on-react-native